# How do I configure log4net so that log.IsDebugEnabled is true?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, configuration, log4net

I am trying to use log4net in an ASP.NET application with Visual Studio 2005. I have declared an instance of the logger like so:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger("")
```

I am trying to use it in the following manner:

```
If log.IsDebugEnabled Then
   log.Debug("Integration Services Constructed")
End If
```

Here is my configuration:

```xml
<log4net>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="..\\logs\\logfile.log"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

</log4net>
```

Unfortunately, `log.IsDebugEnabled` is always false. 
 How do I configure log4net so that I can log only debug messages?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Before calling LogManager.GetLogger("")

You have to call log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
In an ASP.NET app you probably want to put this call in Application_Start

Answer (score 25):

Yes, do it like Anson said.  Also, if you are calling Configure in a class library you can do that by adding an attribute to your class:

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

and if you're using `log4net.config` file, use it like that instead:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a separate configuration file for log4net, do this: after following all the other setup instructions, make sure that u right click on the file in the visual studio solution explorer, select properties, expand the "Advanced" option group, set the "Copy To Output Directory" value as "Copy always". That will do the magic... :) cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are setting log4net up in code rather than in a config file, you can call `log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure` before `GetLogger`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in any  method before you use log :

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

In App.Config ,the settings should be :

```
<root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="AppenderName" />
    </root>
```

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET -

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch:=True)>
```