# Why is IsDebugEnabled always True in my code?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have the following code:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

The problem is the statement below always returns True

```
if (Log.IsDebugEnabled) { /* do time consuming stuff and log the result */
```

This is my log4net config file_

```
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
      <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR" />
    </filter>

    <param name="File" value="Log.txt" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p [%d] - %m%n" />
    </layout>

  </appender>

  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
```

Why does IsDebugEnabled always return True?

Comment: Have you looked at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220021/how-do-i-configure-log4net-so-that-log-isdebugenabled-is-true). The accepted answer looks useful to you

Comment: Where is that IsDebugEnabled set?

Comment: @RB I'm already calling XmlConfigurator.Configure though.

Comment: @Tony It's set by log4net when it reads the config file I presume.

Comment: @Isaac The accepted answer states you need to call it **before** calling Logger.GetLogger()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the log4net manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html):

> Note that by default, the root logger is assigned to Level.DEBUG.

Try:

```
<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
</root>
```

Note that `IsDebugEnabled` is controlled by the logger level.  The fact that you have LevelMin/LevelMax filters on all your appenders doesn't help, because of the loose coupling between loggers and appenders.

Answer (score 1):

define rootCategory for RollingFileAppender

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

before you call the `LogManager.GetLogger` method. I would recommend doing this in startup of your application. Because with the code the way it is now, it is not configuring the logger until after you have already instantiated it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Root Level Value is not been Set.

```
<root>
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
```

By Default, it will take all the Levels.
 By defining the Root Level Value to `INFO`,`WARN`,`ERROR`,and `FATAL` will solve your issue.